# Read bytes from file at desired position with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to open a 50 MB binary file and read only the last 4 bytes and convert it to string for some purpose.

The only way I found to do it now is using `LoadStringFromFile`, to load the file entirely on the memory then copy that last 4 bytes, however this method is very slow because the binary file is heavy.

Is there any better way to do it in Inno Setup script?

---

**Update:** This is a final working function that I edited from Martin Prikryl's answer

```pascal
function readlast4byte() : AnsiString;
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  Buffer: string;
  Count: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Count := 4;

  Stream := TFileStream.Create('C:\test.txt', fmOpenRead);

  try
    Stream.Seek(-Count, soFromEnd);

    SetLength(Buffer, 1);
    SetLength(Result, Count);
    for Index := 1 to Count do
    begin
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, 1);
      Result[Index] := Chr(Ord(Buffer[1]))  ;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

**Update 2:** Also this is another great working function that written by TLama and should mark as answer too:

```pascal
[Code]
#IFNDEF Unicode
  #DEFINE CharSize 1
#ELSE
  #DEFINE CharSize 2
#ENDIF
 
type
  TSeekOrigin = (
    soBeginning,
    soCurrent,
    soEnd
  );
 
#IFDEF UNICODE
function BufferToAnsi(const Buffer: string): AnsiString;
var
  W: Word;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) * 2);
  for I := 1 to Length(Buffer) do
  begin
    W := Ord(Buffer[I]);
    Result[(I * 2)] := Chr(W shr 8); // high byte
    Result[(I * 2) - 1] := Chr(Byte(W)); // low byte
  end;
end;
#ENDIF
 
function ReadStringFromFile(
  const FileName: string; Origin: TSeekOrigin; Offset, Length: Integer;
  var S: AnsiString): Boolean;
var
  Buffer: string;
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
    try
      Stream.Seek(Offset, Ord(Origin));
      SetLength(Buffer, Length div {#CharSize});
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, Length);
      #IFNDEF UNICODE
        S := Buffer;
      #ELSE
        S := BufferToAnsi(Buffer);
      #ENDIF
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TFileStream` [support class](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses):

```pascal
TStream = class(TObject)
  function Read(Buffer: String; Count: Longint): Longint;
  function Write(Buffer: String; Count: Longint): Longint;
  function Seek(Offset: Longint; Origin: Word): Longint;
  procedure ReadBuffer(Buffer: String; Count: Longint);
  procedure WriteBuffer(Buffer: String; Count: Longint);
  function CopyFrom(Source: TStream; Count: Longint): Longint;
  property Position: Longint; read write;
  property Size: Longint; read write;
end;

THandleStream = class(TStream)
  constructor Create(AHandle: Integer);
  property Handle: Integer; read;
end;

TFileStream = class(THandleStream)
  constructor Create(Filename: String; Mode: Word);
end;
```

Use the `.Seek(-4, soFromEnd)` property to seek the read pointer to the desired position.

A complication is that the `TStream` works with characters not bytes, so you have to convert Unicode strings that your read back to bytes.

When reading just four bytes, it's way easier to read byte by byte, preventing any multibyte conversions:

```pascal
procedure ReadFileEnd;
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  Buffer: string;
  Count: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Count := 4;

  Stream := TFileStream.Create('my_binary_file.dat', fmOpenRead);

  try
    Stream.Seek(-Count, soFromEnd);

    SetLength(Buffer, 1);
    for Index := 1 to Count do
    begin
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, 1);
      Log(Format('Byte %2.2x: %2.2x', [Index, Ord(Buffer[1])]));
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

Here's a generic alternative from by @TLama that efficiently works for arbitrary large read:
https://pastebin.com/nzGEdXVj

---

By the way, for me [`LoadStringFromFile` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringfromfile) seems to be efficient enough to load 50 MB file. It takes only 40 ms.