# how to tap powershell script executing progress to inno setup

Tags: windows, cmd, inno-setup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8IgF.png)I have few powershell script which is having convert-vhd executing. It is showing progress in powershell window. However I am running this powershell script from inside another inno script and I want to report convert-vhd progress in the inno script.

I found [Inno Setup - Make Inno Setup Installer report its installation progress status to master installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947436/inno-setup-make-inno-setup-installer-report-its-installation-progress-status-t)
 and
[Inno Setup torrent download implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924722/inno-setup-torrent-download-implementation)

And I tried to apply the same for powershell. But the the pipe command in cmd.exe is not reading the progress from powershell window.
Is it possible to get that progress in inno ?

I want to read the progress shown in the image. It is powershell's own progress bar which I want to tap to inno setup.

Comment: So, you need to get the output of a Powershell command, or the actual progress percentage? I have some code in Delphi to get a cmd output, but if you need to respond to a specific value you'd have to parse the output strings or something. In any case, since Inno's Pascal Scripting doesn't cover this stuff, you could build a DLL and import it into your Inno Script, but again, I'm not sure what it is you want.

Comment: What do you mean by “pipe command in cmd.exe”? And what does it have to do with your question? Show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: Found a probable solution to run the command with -AsJob and then read the progress using get-job. Working on it and trying to read that in inno setup.